# Path.resolve() is losing relative information in Python

Tags: python, pathlib

The following code using Path() is losing relative information:

```
    src_file=inspect.getfile(CompileTypeData)
    logger.debug(f'SRC_FILE: {src_file}')
    src_path = Path(src_file).resolve()
    logger.debug(f'SRC_PATH: {src_path}')
    logger.debug(f'SRC_DIRNAME: {src_path.parent}')
```

Produces this:

```
 DEBUG:from_project_types_file:SRC_FILE: ../../build_compile_mod/compile_type.py
 DEBUG:from_project_types_file:SRC_PATH: /build_compile_mod/compile_type.py
 DEBUG:from_project_types_file:SRC_DIRNAME: /build_compile_mod
```

What happened to my relative paths?  It's my understanding that resolve() should make this an absolute path rather than losing data.

Comment: Where are you? Are you in the root directory?

Comment: What's the current working directory? If it's something like `/spam/eggs` (or just `/spam`), then `../..` will resolve to `/`.'

Comment: Turns out this is what's going on.

I'm running in /tmp/testdir_nnn

The sources is in ../../build_compile_mod relative to the test source code.

So the inspect.getfile is delivering a path that is actually NOT relative to my cwd.  It's relative to the source.

Comment: I need to figure out how to get inspect.getfile() to return an absolute path.

Comment: Ah, you need to combine the relative path to your source with the relative path _of_ the source, and _then_ call `resolve`.

Comment: I think you want to use the `dirname` of `__file__` , although I'm not 100% sure; you may want `sys.argv[0]` instead of `__file__`, or the former on Windows but the latter on POSIX…

Comment: I think the problem is that, at core,`__file__` is set to `../../mod_dir`.

You'd think it would use absolute paths.

Comment: The real problem is that I used `sys.path.insert` to insert a relative path into the path. This caused `__file__` to have a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

`my_path.resolve()` accepts an additional parameter, `strict` that defaults to `False`. If set to `True`, it raises a `FileNotFoundError` if the path cannot be resolved to an absolute path. That could be used to assess whether pathlib has enough data to create an absolute path from the string you obtained with `inspect.getfile()`.

`inspect.getfile()` does not always return an absolute path, but you can always convert that path using `os.path.realpath(inspect.getfile(obj))`, or using `Path.relative_to(...)` method in combination with `os.path.realpath(__file__)`.

Comment: No joy there.  Same behavior.

Comment: Though I do get the FileNotFound exception.

Comment: That means that your path object does not point to an existing path.

Comment: I changed directories on it. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

### Example of Relative Paths and `sys.path.insert`

If you put relative paths in to `sys.path` using
`sys.path.insert` and change directories while 
running the script, then you'll get wrong answers
trying to use `__file__` or anything derived from
it.

Say we have this:

```
 /tmp/test1
 /tmp/test2
 /tmp/test2/mymod.py
 /tmp/rundir/rundir2
```

So we CD to `/tmp/test2/ and launch the script.

```
% cd /tmp/test2
```

Now we create this script in Test2 that defines
`show_path()` which finds the path to `mymod.py`
and prints it.

Notice that `sys.path.insert` uses a relative path
this is the problem.

```
 import sys
 sys.path.insert(0,'../test1')
 from mymod import *
 import inspect  
 from pathlib import Path

 def show_path():
     myClassFile=inspect.getfile(MyClass)
     print(Path(myClassFile).resolve())
```

So now we run our script.  It starts in `/tmp/test2/`
it then changes directory and runs `show_path()`.

Notice that `show_path()` points to nowhere because
of the relative path.

```
 import os
 os.chdir('/tmp/rundir/rundir2')
 show_path()
```

This gives the following incorrect output.

```
/private/tmp/rundir/test1/mymod.py
```

Comment: One more note on this. I've included an argument in the puunit setUp() method so that I can say setUp(change_dir=False) and I don't change directories.   I did that in this case to solve the problem.

Comment: A possibility could be to compute (1) the path from your script (before cd) to the file (../../build_compile_mod), (2) the path from your script (before cd) to the script (after cd), (3) combine both in some way :-) (I'm not really helping there, sorry ^^)

Comment: What I do is save the directory in my base testCase class before CDing.  But this code is in my tested software, and my test situation is really pathological relative to actual usage. So It's up to the tester to figure it out since the source code is doing the right thing.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a minimal reproducible example? It's seem to be more involved that what I initially thought;)

Comment: Would it be possible to insert an absolute path in sys.path instead of a relative one in your case?

Comment: @Guybrush, yes, that's what I did using environment variables.